# VMWare Virtual Machine Network Adapter will not bridge

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I copy VM's between harddrives and it never fails that the network adapter can't pick up an IP address when in Bridge mode.  I always have to (ipconfig /release * /renew) to recover.  No biggie.

This time however, I have copied top virtual machines (to separate external hard drives) and they will not bridge.  They want to acquire an internal IP (169....).   I have tried the following to no avail:

Within the Virtual Machine

- Disabled/Renabled
- Uninstalled / reinstalled
- Uninstalled / reinstalled VMTools (wasn't sure if any of the network drivers were associated with VMTools
- rebooted

From the Host

- removed / added network adapter
- From (Edit - Virtual Network settings) restored defaults
- Made sure only physical network was connected (no wireless)
- Rebooted
- tried an assortment of settings for the bridged (replicate physical connection / or not)

The only way I can get the network connection to work is if I manually assign the IP/Gateway/DNS server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you look at the "Virtual Network Editor" for any weirdness? You can get to this through the "Edit" menu in VMware Workstation.

Comment: Yes, that was where I said I "Restored details".  Just noticed that StackExchange brutalized my layout.

Comment: Ahh... I see! Sorry about that. It all kind of ran together... lol... Good Job at fixing it @pghtech. I'm not sure of what to do now to fix your problem. Normally stuff just works. DHCP works just fine for me all the time, but then again, I am not moving my VMs between HDDs

Comment: Did you checked your DHCP server?

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, it turned out to be the DHCP server ran out of IP addy's.

Comment: Heh - been caught by that myself!

Comment: Maannnn, same issue here. After prompting the admin to check DHCP leases he found out we had many 'infinite' leases eating up the space.